# Dart class dot notation like JS objects

Tags: oop, dart

We switched to Flutter due to the instability of React Native. I cannot describe the happiness of working with a stable resource.

I created a structure for myself in React Native. I was able to access the pages with the "dot" notation both in JSX and in functions by creating static under a main class of components. How healthy the suspect is. Like this: `<Component.Form.Input />`

Since darts is purely an object language, I could not find an example of this type of structure. Even if I connect the static design of my root class element with the "Singleton" design pattern to the instance, I cannot access the methods below the linked class.

`Helpers.Responsive.calcSome(params..)`

In the example above, Helper is a class, Responsive is a separate class, and Helper is imported and assigned as a static variable. The calcSome function is a method of the Responsive class. How can I do this with Dart?

This is exactly what I want to do. You can think of each other as a chained class.

Of course, I do not know how healthy this approach will be for a clean code.

If you have different approaches that can work this way, please share as an alternative. I have an idea of how I should proceed.

Thank you for interest.

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR**: Not possible or not useful in your case. [Namespaces don't exist *per se* in Dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13876879/how-do-you-namespace-a-dart-class)

**Long version**

- Only variables or methods can be dot accessed. See documentation for [Classes](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#classes) and [Operators](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#other-operators).
- The only approach I can think of, to be able to use `a.b.c` is to Define `b` as a static member with a getter, that returns an instantiated class. This is usually helpful for Singletons, for example as used in Firebase:

```dart
class FirebaseAuth {
  // ...
  static FirebaseAuth get instance {
    FirebaseApp defaultAppInstance = Firebase.app();

    if (!_firebaseAuthInstances.containsKey(defaultAppInstance.name)) {
      _firebaseAuthInstances[defaultAppInstance.name] = FirebaseAuth._(
        app: Firebase.app(),
      );
    }

    return _firebaseAuthInstances[defaultAppInstance.name];
  }
  // ...
}
```

- If you were to use the above to return a class with only static members, I'm afraid [that is against best practices](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/design#avoid-defining-a-class-that-contains-only-static-members) of Dart.

**Recommendation**

In your particular case I would have `calcSome` defined in a `helpers/responsive.dart` file. If you have a lot of different helpers, you can make a library out of it.